# 'await' expression is only allowed within an async function

Tags: angular, rxjs, ionic3, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I have an async method like below. It shows an error `[ts] 'await' expression is only allowed within an async function.` here `await userProfile.set({`. Can you tell me how to sort out it?

**Note:** Maybe it is due to I have tried to call `promise` inside the `observable`. Any clue?

```js
 async loginWithGoogle(): Promise<void> {
    const result = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
    const userId: string = result.uid;
    const userProfile: AngularFirestoreDocument<UserProfile> = this.fireStore.doc(`userProfile/${userId}`);
    const userProfiles: AngularFirestoreCollection<UserProfile> = this.fireStore.collection('userProfile/', ref => ref.where('email', '==', result.email));
    const userProfiles$: Observable<UserProfile[]> = userProfiles.valueChanges();
    userProfiles$.subscribe(res => {
      if (res == null) {
        await userProfile.set({ //here it shows error
          id: userId,
          email: result.email,
          creationTime: moment().format(),
          lastSignInTime: moment().format()
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Your main function is async but you’re using `await` in an arrow function which isn’t declared as `async`

```
userProfiles$.subscribe(async res => {
  if (res == null) {
    await userProfile.set({
...
```

Comment: Yes, That is fixed. But am I doing right way here? calling `promise` inside the `observable/subscribe`?

Comment: Above leads to another issue.Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710673/internal-assertion-failed-asyncqueue-is-already-failed

Comment: Thanks for the help. Above issue maybe due to `firestore` issue. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/hjng5VgktPM